# Visual Studio 2005 Setup project application folder default location on potentially non-existent volume

Tags: visual-studio-2005, installation, defaultlocation

I have a Visual Studio 2005 solution that includes a setup project. The setup project specifies "d:\somefolder" as the Application Folder DefaultLocation property.  When installing on a machine without any partitions mapped to "d:", the resulting installer craps out with the message

> "The volume d:\ is currently unavailable. Please select another."

Trouble is, you don't actually get a chance to select a different install location (on an existing volume). What settings should I use to enable the user of the installer to change the install path, while keeping the default as d:\some_folder?

Answer (score 1):

the Setup and Deployment projects from VS leave quite a bit to be desired.  Every solution I am aware of will take a bit of reading and learning, as the GUI tools that make setup's for you are normally rather limiting in customization outside the realm of changing the actual look of it.  I would recommend looking into the [WiX (Windows Installer XML)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) toolset for making installations.  The learning curve is one of the most user friendly ones that I have seen on the market, plus it is a free tool. As long as you have a fairly decent understanding of XML you have everything that you need in order to start making MSI's.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there should be setups available which let you change the destination.

Or you could use orca to add in a dialog box which specifies that.

Or you could pass it in as a commandline argument if the user is on a commandline interface.

Comment: re: other setups: not sure I know what you mean... like plugins for VS that result in different setup projects?

re: Orca: cool tool, but it looks like learning to use it will take a bit of time;  i'm certainly not clear on how to insert the necessary step.

re: commandline: not an option

Comment: @fakeleft: Not much experience with creating setup projects here, but I suppose when you create a setup project for something, there are options as to which template do you want to use. And there should be one that lets you specify where to install.